# BeautifulSoup returns None, but element exists

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, datatables

I have gone through most of the solutions for similar issues but haven't found one that works and more importantly haven't found an explanation of why this occurs outside of when Javascript or something else is being called on the site being scraped.

I am trying to scrape the table from https://www.bundeskartellamt.de/DE/Fusionskontrolle/LaufendeVerfahren/laufendeverfahren_node.html

my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.bundeskartellamt.de/DE/Fusionskontrolle/LaufendeVerfahren/laufendeverfahren_node.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'left')

print (table)
```

Can someone with a better understanding of html help me on what is different about this webpage specifically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see class attribute equal to `"left"` in the html. What are you trying to pull? I do see `class="csvTable"`. Further more, if you are after `<table>` tags, go with pandas' `.read_html()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

r=requests.get('https://www.bundeskartellamt.de/DE/Fusionskontrolle/
LaufendeVerfahren/laufendeverfahren_node.html',headers = user_agent)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_= 'csvTable')
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's returning None because you are telling bs4 to find the `<table>` tag that has the class attribute value of `"left"`. I don't see that in the html source. There is however the class value `"csvTable"` (see image).

[image]

However, if you are going after `<table>` tags, let pandas do the work for you. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood and will parse the table tags for you. It' will return a list of dfs for each `<table>` tag in the html.

```
import pandas as pd
url ='https://www.bundeskartellamt.de/DE/Fusionskontrolle/LaufendeVerfahren/laufendeverfahren_node.html'

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
          Datum Aktenzeichen                                        Unternehmen                                    Produktbereiche                                         Bundesland                               Abschluss
0    30.04.2020     B7-99/20  GIC (Re­al­ty) Pri­va­te Li­mi­ted (SGP) und E...              Re­chen­zen­trums­dienst­leis­tun­gen                                                  -                                       -
1    30.04.2020     B2-67/20  AGRA­VIS Nie­der­sach­sen-Süd GmbH,Wunstorf; E...                                       Land­han­del                                   Nie­der­sach­sen                                       -
2    29.04.2020     B5-57/20  CGS Ma­nage­ment / EOL Packa­ging Ex­perts / B...  Pa­cker, Pa­let­tier­an­la­gen, Se­kun­där­ver...                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
3    29.04.2020     B7-98/20  The Pa­ra­gon Fund III GmbH & Co. ge­schlos­se...  Be­ra­tungs- und Schu­lungs­dienst­leis­tun­ge...                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
4    29.04.2020     B3-73/20  Ep­pen­dorf AG, Ham­burg (D); Er­werb des Zen­...                               Tisch­zen­tri­fu­gen                                           Ham­burg                                       -
5    29.04.2020     B9-61/20  equens­World­li­ne SE Ger­ma­ny, Frank­furt am...  Dienst­leis­tun­gen zur Ab­wick­lung des na­ti...                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
6    29.04.2020     B8-52/20  West­netz GmbH, Dort­mund und Ener­gie- und Wa...                                                Gas                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
7    28.04.2020     B3-71/20  Sau­di Ba­sic In­dus­tries Cor­po­ra­ti­on, Ri...                           Spe­zial­che­mi­ka­li­en                                                  -                                       -
8    28.04.2020     B7-97/20  Pres­se-Ver­trieb Dres­den GmbH & Co. KG, Dres...                               Pres­se-Groß­han­del                              Sach­sen, Thü­rin­gen                                       -
9    28.04.2020     B3-72/20  Al­fred Clouth Lack­fa­brik GmbH & Co. KG, Of­...                          Far­ben und Maler­be­darf                                            Hes­sen                                       -
10   27.04.2020     B5-56/20  The Pa­ra­gon Fund III / Cas­to­lin Eu­tec­tic...  Füll­dräh­te, Hart­löt­ma­te­ria­li­en, Schutz...                                   Bay­ern, Hes­sen                                       -
11   27.04.2020     B3-70/20  As­kle­pi­os Kli­ni­ken GmbH & Co. KGaA, Ham­b...  Dienst­leis­tun­gen von Re­ha­bi­li­ta­ti­ons­...                                            Bay­ern                                       -
12   24.04.2020     B9-49/20  Al­li­anz Stra­te­gic In­vest­ments S.à.r.l., ...  Sach­ver­si­che­run­gen, Scha­dens­ab­wick­lun...                                                  -                                       -
13   24.04.2020     B8-51/20  GE­TEC ENER­GIE GmbH, Han­no­ver; An­teil­s­er...                                              Strom                          Ber­lin, Nie­der­sach­sen                                       -
14   24.04.2020     B9-60/20  TE­LIS Fi­nan­ci­al­Ser­vices­Hol­ding AG, Re­...               Ver­mitt­lung von Ver­si­che­run­gen                      Bay­ern, Schles­wig-Hol­stein                                       -
15   24.04.2020     B5-55/20  Skan­di­na­vis­ka Ens­kil­da Ban­ken / V-Vä­ge...              Leuch­ten, Leucht­mit­tel, Sen­so­ren                                                  -                                       -
16   24.04.2020     B7-96/20  Schnei­der Elec­tric SE, Ru­eil-Mal­mai­son (F...                                      MES-Soft­ware                                            Bay­ern                                       -
17   23.04.2020     B9-59/20  A. Ehr­mann GmbH & Co. KG Mol­ke­rei, Ober­sch...             Ho­tel­be­trieb, Ho­te­lim­mo­bi­li­en                                            Bay­ern                                       -
18   23.04.2020     B6-31/20  Ip­pen-Me­dien­grup­pe, Mün­chen; Er­werb der ...                   di­gi­ta­le Wer­be­ver­mark­tung                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
19   23.04.2020     B2-65/20  1. Rot­käpp­chen-Mumm Sekt­kel­le­rei­en GmbH,...                                               Wein                                   Sach­sen-An­halt                                       -
20   23.04.2020     B1-94/20  Swiss Li­fe Hol­ding AG, Zü­rich; Mit­tel­ba­r...                              Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­lie                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
21   22.04.2020     B8-50/20  Mai­no­va AG, Frank­furt und Duss­mann Ser­vic...                       Elek­tro­mo­bi­li­tät, Strom                                   Ber­lin, Hes­sen                                       -
22   22.04.2020     B1-93/20  AGC Glass Eu­ro­pe S.A., Lou­vain-La-Neu­ve, B...                                                NaN                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
23   21.04.2020     B1-92/20  Panat­to­ni Ger­ma­ny Hol­ding S.a.r.l., Lu­xe...                             Pro­jekt­ent­wick­lung                                            Hes­sen                                       -
24   21.04.2020     B8-49/20  BGZ Ge­sell­schaft für Zwi­schen­la­ge­rung mb...                                   Strah­len­schutz       Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
25   20.04.2020     B8-48/20  Eu­ro­pean Di­ver­si­fied In­fra­struc­ture Fu...                   Fern­wär­me, Gas, Strom, Was­ser                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                                       -
26   20.04.2020     B6-30/20  1. Main In­cu­ba­tor GmbH, Frank­furt a. M.; 2...                               Con­tent Mar­ke­ting                                   Bay­ern, Hes­sen                                       -
27   17.04.2020     B2-64/20  Uni­ted Pet­food Pro­du­cers N.V.,Gent (B); Er...                    Hun­de­fut­ter, Kat­zen­fut­ter                                                  -                                       -
28   16.04.2020     B1-91/20  Leon­hard Weiss Be­tei­li­gungs­hol­ding GmbH,...                                                NaN                      Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Hes­sen                                       -
29   14.04.2020     B7-92/20  In­vest­corp Bank B.S.C., Ma­na­ma (BHR); mit­...                Si­cher­heits­soft­wa­re­lö­sun­gen                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 23.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
30   14.04.2020     B3-69/20  Hunts­man Cor­po­ra­ti­on, Te­xas, (USA), Er­w...             Epoxid­har­ze, Epoxid­ver­dün­ner etc.                                                  -                 23.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
31   14.04.2020     B7-95/20  Al­li­anz SE, Mün­chen; mit­tel­ba­rer An­teil...  IT-Be­ra­tungs­dienst­leis­tun­gen im Be­reich...                                            Bay­ern                 22.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
32   14.04.2020     B9-58/20  Rhenus Re­ser­va 30 GmbH, Hol­zwicke­de; Er­we...  Kon­trakt­lo­gis­tik, Spe­di­ti­ons­dienst­lei...                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
33   14.04.2020     B1-90/20  Franz Ha­niel & Cie. GmbH, Duis­burg; Er­werb ...                                                NaN                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
34   14.04.2020     B7-93/20  Ax­cel Ma­nage­ment A/S, Ko­pen­ha­gen (DNK); ...                                      CRM-Soft­ware                                                  -                                       -
35   09.04.2020     B4-56/20  Rec­ti­cel und TEM­DA-1 GmbH; Er­werb der ge­m...       In­nen­aus­stat­tungs­kom­po­nen­ten für KfZ                                            Bay­ern                 27.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
36   09.04.2020     B4-57/20  Er­werb we­sent­li­cher Ver­mö­gens­tei­le der...                               KFZ-Zu­be­hör­tei­le                     Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Ham­burg                                       -
37   07.04.2020     B1-88/20  EL­CO In­ter­na­tio­nal GmbH, He­chin­gen; An­...                                                NaN                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 14.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
38   07.04.2020     B8-47/20  Ma­xim In­te­gra­ted Pro­ducts Inc., San José ...        Halb­lei­ter, In­te­grier­te Schalt­krei­se                                           Ham­burg                                       -
39   07.04.2020     B1-89/20            JM­HL GmbH/DAL/Grün­dung der Da­thor KG                            Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­li­en    Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Hes­sen, Rhein­land-Pfalz                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
40   06.04.2020     B4-54/20  So­cie­te fe­deral de Par­ti­ci­pa­ti­ons et d...      Kom­po­nen­ten für die Flug­zeu­g­in­dus­trie                                                  -                                       -
41   06.04.2020     B5-53/20  Gui­do R. Krass, Ober­wil-Lie­li (CH); An­teil...  Hei­zungs-Kli­ma-Lüf­tungs­tech­nik für Wohn­g...                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 15.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
42   06.04.2020     B1-87/20  Fra­port Ca­sa Com­mer­ci­al GmbH, Neu-Isen­bu...                             Pro­jekt­ent­wick­lung                                            Hes­sen                 24.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
43   06.04.2020     B9-57/20  Pro­vin­zi­al Nord­West Hol­ding AG, Müns­ter ...                                 Ver­si­che­run­gen                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                                       -
44   03.04.2020     B1-86/20  Han­sain­vest Han­sea­ti­sche In­vest­ment-Ge­...                    Ein­zel­han­del­sim­mo­bi­li­en                                  Ham­burg, Hes­sen                 29.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
45   03.04.2020     B7-89/20  Ufenau Ca­pi­tal Part­ners AG, Präf­fi­kon (CH...               IT-Dienst­leis­tun­gen IT-Be­ra­tung                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 16.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
46   03.04.2020     B1-85/20  MP Be­tei­li­gungs KG/An­teils- und Kon­trol­l...       Ein­zel­han­del mit Mö­beln, Pols­ter­mö­bel          Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len, Sach­sen                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
47   03.04.2020     B9-56/20  Arch Ca­pi­tal Group Ltd., Ha­mil­ton, Ber­mu­...  Bürg­schaf­ten , Fac­to­ring, Kre­dit­ver­si­c...                                                  -                 09.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
48   03.04.2020     B9-55/20  ape­ti­to ca­te­ring B.V. & Co KG, Rhei­ne; Ev...          Ca­te­ring, Ge­mein­schafts­ver­pfle­gung                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 22.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
49   03.04.2020     B4-53/20  Daim­ler AG, Stutt­gart; Er­werb von Uku­ve­la...                     Mo­tor­blö­cke aus Guss­ei­sen                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 30.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
50   02.04.2020     B1-84/20  In­ter­Xi­on Re­al Estate XXII B.V., Hoofd­dor...                            Han­del­sim­mo­bi­li­en                                            Hes­sen                 22.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
51   02.04.2020     B5-52/20  Ver­äu­ße­rung der SA­MAG Ma­chi­ne Tools GmbH...  Ent­wick­lung Her­stel­lung und Ver­trieb von ...                      Nie­der­sach­sen, Thü­rin­gen                 15.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
52   02.04.2020     B7-88/20  AUC­TUS Ma­nage­ment GmbH & Co. KG, Grün­wald;...  IT-Dienst­leis­tun­gen IT-Be­ra­tung, IT-Sys­t...                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 16.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
53   01.04.2020     B1-82/20  Baye­ri­sche Lan­des­bank Im­mo­bi­li­en-Be­te...                             Pro­jekt­ent­wick­lung                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 23.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
54   01.04.2020     B1-83/20  Stadt Karls­ru­he, Karls­ru­he; Er­werb von Im...                                Bü­ro­flä­chen u.a.                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 24.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
55   01.04.2020     B4-52/20  Ve­ri­tas Hol­ding Com­pa­ny, Le­wes (USA); An...                                         Schläu­che                                            Hes­sen                 14.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
56   01.04.2020     B8-46/20  EWE Er­neu­er­ba­re Ener­gi­en GmbH, Ol­den­bu...                                          EEG-Strom                          Ber­lin, Nie­der­sach­sen                 21.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
57   01.04.2020     B8-37/20  BA­LAN­CE Er­neu­er­ba­re Ener­gi­en GmbH, Lei...           Bio­gas, Bio­me­than, EEG-Strom, Erd­gas               Meck­len­burg-Vor­pom­mern, Sach­sen                 16.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
58   01.04.2020     B6-28/20  Me­dia­set S.p.A., Co­lo­gno Mon­ze­se (ITA); ...                    Pro­duk­ti­on von TV-In­hal­ten                                            Bay­ern                                       -
59   01.04.2020     B3-68/20  Ko­ri­an Deutsch­land AG, Mün­chen. Er­werb sä...  Am­bu­lan­te und sta­tio­näre Pfle­ge­dienst­l...                          Bay­ern, Nie­der­sach­sen                 30.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
60   01.04.2020     B7-87/20  Frank­furt Busi­ness Me­dia GmbH, Frank­furt a...                Fach­zeit­schrif­ten, Web­por­ta­le                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
61   31.03.2020     B9-54/20  SOST­NT Lu­xem­bourg S.à.r.l.; Über­nah­me ei­...      Rei­se­ver­an­stal­tung, Rei­se­ver­mitt­lung                                            Bay­ern                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
62   30.03.2020     B8-45/20  lek­ker Ener­gie GmbH, Ber­lin; Er­werb ei­nes...  SLP-Gas auf Ba­sis von Son­der­ver­trä­gen, SL...                    Ber­lin, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len  28.04.2020 (*Form­lo­se Ein­stel­lung)
63   30.03.2020     B1-81/20  Bau­haus Ge­sell­schaft für Bau- und Haus­be­d...                                                NaN                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 23.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
64   30.03.2020     B9-53/20  Avis Bud­get Au­to­ver­mie­tung GmbH & Co. KG,...                                 Au­to­ver­mie­tung                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
65   27.03.2020     B1-79/20  Merz Re­al Estate GmbH & Co. KG, Frank­furt/M....                  Wohn- und Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­li­en                                            Hes­sen                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
66   27.03.2020     B1-80/20  Apol­lo EPF Ma­nage­ment III, LLC, New York; E...                      Ga­le­ria Kauf­hof Fi­lia­len                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 15.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
67   27.03.2020     B9-51/20  TUI AG, Han­no­ver und DER Tou­ris­tik Group G...  In­sol­venz­si­che­rung von Rei­se­ver­an­stal...                    Ber­lin, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
68   27.03.2020     B8-44/20  Open Grid Eu­ro­pe GmbH, TÜV Süd AG und Hor­vá...  Un­ter­neh­mens­be­ra­tung in der Was­ser­stof...  Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West...                 24.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
69   26.03.2020     B8-23/20  Ava­con Na­tur GmbH, Sars­tedt und Stadt­wer­k...           Käl­te­ver­sor­gung, Wär­me­ver­sor­gung                   Nord­rhein-West­fa­len, Sach­sen                 24.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
70   26.03.2020     B7-86/20  vi­tro­net GmbH, Es­sen; An­teils- und Kon­tro...  Ent­stö­rung von Kup­fer­ka­bel­net­zen, Er­ri...                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
71   26.03.2020     B1-78/20  Lau­ra Hol­ding GmbH, Inns­bruck; Er­werb von ...                             Pro­jekt­ent­wick­lung                                                  -                 03.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
72   26.03.2020     B1-77/20  Com­merz Re­al Bau­ma­na­ge­ment GmbH, Düs­sel...                            Pro­jekt­ge­sell­schaft       Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 03.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
73   25.03.2020     B4-51/20  GI In­ter­na­tio­nal S.R.L., Ita­li­en; Er­wer...                     Per­so­nal­dienst­leis­tun­gen                                                  -                 17.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
74   25.03.2020     B4-50/20  Faun Um­welt­tech­nik GmbH & Co.KG, Os­ter­hol...                     War­tung von Nutz­fahr­zeu­gen                                            Bre­men                 22.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
75   25.03.2020     B8-43/20  Niss­hin­bo Hol­dings Inc., To­kio (JP); mit­t...  Groß­han­del mit Elek­tro­nik­pro­duk­ten und ...                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 21.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
76   25.03.2020     B3-67/20  Klin­ge Phar­ma (D); Er­werb drei­er Haut­pfle...                            Haut­pfle­ge­pro­duk­te                                                  -                 23.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
77   25.03.2020     B7-85/20  Fi­du­cia & GAD IT AG, Karls­ru­he, und BMS Be...  Be­ra­tungs­leis­tun­gen im Be­reich der Di­gi...       Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 21.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
78   24.03.2020     B1-76/20  Dorsch Hol­ding GmbH, Of­fen­bach; Er­werb säm...  Pla­nungs- und In­ge­nieur­be­ra­tungs­dienst­...                                   Bay­ern, Hes­sen                 30.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
79   23.03.2020     B7-83/20  vi­tro­net GmbH, Es­sen; An­teils- und Kon­tro...  Er­rich­tung und In­stal­la­ti­on von Glas­fa­...                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
80   23.03.2020     B2-60/20  Pep­si­Co, Inc. (USA); Er­werb der Ge­trän­ke­...  Ener­gie­ge­trän­ke Ener­gy­drinks, al­ko­hol­...                                                  -                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
81   23.03.2020     B9-50/20  Hauck & Auf­häu­ser Pri­vat­ban­kiers AG, Fran...                           Bank­dienst­leis­tun­gen                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 30.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
82   23.03.2020     B1-74/20  Baye­ri­sche Lan­des­bank Im­mo­bi­li­en-Be­te...                             Pro­jekt­ent­wick­lung                                            Bay­ern                 01.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
83   23.03.2020     B8-41/20  Au­to­bahn Tank & Rast GmbH, Bonn und Adolf Pr...  Ad­Blue, Die­sel­kraft­stoff, LPG, Ot­to­kraft...                    Hes­sen, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 03.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
84   20.03.2020     B1-75/20  Ger­man Op­por­tu­ni­ties IV GmbH & Co. Ge­sch...                                Bü­ro­flä­chen u.a.                                            Hes­sen                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
85   20.03.2020     B8-39/20  Saa­le Ener­gie GmbH, Schko­pau; Er­werb sämt­...                                    Elek­tri­zi­tät                                   Sach­sen-An­halt                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
86   20.03.2020     B8-38/20  ROLLS-ROY­CE POWER SYS­TEMS AG, Fried­richs­ha...   Die­sel­mo­to­ren, Strom­ver­sor­gungs­sys­te­me                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
87   20.03.2020     B5-51/20  Han­no­ver Fi­nanz / Kretz + Wahl-Grup­pe (An­...                          Luft- und Kli­ma­tech­nik                          Hes­sen, Nie­der­sach­sen                 27.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
88   20.03.2020     B7-82/20  BMC Soft­ware, Inc., Hou­ston (USA); An­teils-...                             Main­f­ra­me-Soft­ware                                                  -                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
89   19.03.2020     B5-50/20  Do­ver Cor­po­ra­ti­on / em-tec (An­teils- und...  Durch­fluss­mes­ser, nicht-in­va­si­ve Durch­f...                             Bay­ern, Bran­den­burg                 25.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
90   19.03.2020     B5-49/20  MTX Group / Stroj­me­tal & KSP / SPO­LECNY POD...  Han­del mit Alu­mi­ni­um­le­gie­run­gen, Her­s...                                                  -                 20.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
91   19.03.2020     B3-65/20  Ho­ney­well Chi­na Co., Ltd; (CHN); Zhe­ji­ang...                        Hy­drier­ka­ta­ly­sa­to­ren                                                  -                 07.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
92   19.03.2020     B7-81/20  Wat­ch­Guard Tech­no­lo­gies, Inc., Se­att­le ...                Si­cher­heits­soft­wa­re­lö­sun­gen                                                  -                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
93   18.03.2020     B1-73/20  Op­ti-Wohn­welt Föst GmbH & Co. KG, Nie­der­la...                              Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­lie                          Hes­sen, Rhein­land-Pfalz                 31.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
94   18.03.2020     B7-80/20  Er­gon Ca­pi­tal Part­ners IV SCSp (LUX); mit­...  Soft­wa­re­lö­sun­gen im Be­reich Fahr­zeuglea...                                                  -                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
95   18.03.2020     B1-72/20  Op­ti Wohn­welt Föst GmbH & Co. KG, Nie­der­la...                              Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­lie                          Hes­sen, Rhein­land-Pfalz                 31.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
96   17.03.2020     B3-64/20  STA­DA Arz­nei­mit­tel AG, Bad Vil­bel (D); Er...  re­zept­freie Er­käl­tungs­prä­pa­ra­te Hal­sp...                                            Hes­sen                 30.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
97   17.03.2020     B3-63/20  Es­si­ty Hy­gie­ne und He­alth AB, Gö­te­borg ...                      Wund­ver­sor­gungs­pro­duk­te                                                  -                 31.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
98   17.03.2020     B3-62/20  Ver­sa­lis Deutsch­land GmbH, Esch­born (D) (E...  Po­ly­ethy­len, po­ly­ethy­len-ba­sier­te Ver­...                                            Hes­sen                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
99   17.03.2020     B8-40/20  Deut­sche Woh­nen SE, Ber­lin und Ar­bo­nia AG...  Di­gi­ta­le Zu­gangs­sys­te­me für Ein­gang­st...                                            Ber­lin                 02.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
100  17.03.2020     B7-79/20  Beck Ver­mö­gens­ver­wal­tungs GmbH, Mün­chen;...  Soft­ware für Ju­ris­ten Steu­er­be­ra­ter Wir...                                   Bay­ern, Ber­lin                24.03.2020 (Rück­nah­me)
101  16.03.2020     B4-47/20  Ma­di­son Dear­born Part­ners, LLC (USA); Er­w...                     Per­so­nal­dienst­leis­tun­gen                                                  -                 01.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
102  16.03.2020     B1-71/20  Al­li­anz NM 28 GmbH & Co. KG, Stutt­gart; Er­...                                Bü­roim­mo­bi­li­en       Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 25.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
103  16.03.2020     B7-78/20  Wa­ter­land Pri­va­te Equi­ty Fund VII C.V., B...  IT-Dienst­leis­tun­gen IT-Be­ra­tung, Ver­trie...                                  Bay­ern, Ham­burg                 03.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
104  13.03.2020     B3-61/20  Sie­mens Ak­ti­en­ge­sell­schaft, Mün­chen (D)...  Her­stel­lung und Ver­trieb von tech­ni­schen ...                                            Bay­ern                 23.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
105  13.03.2020     B4-48/20  Akiem Group SAS, Frank­reich; Er­werb des Be­t...                       Lea­sing von Lo­ko­mo­ti­ven                                            Hes­sen                 09.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
106  13.03.2020     B7-77/20  OEP Ca­pi­tal Ad­vi­sors, L.P., New York (USA)...     Ver­trieb von Hard- und Soft­wa­re­pro­duk­ten                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 30.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
107  13.03.2020     B7-76/20  Schnei­der Elec­tric SE, Ru­eil Mal­mai­son (F...                                   5D BIM-Soft­ware                               Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
108  13.03.2020     B5-47/20  Bobst Group / CI­TO-Sys­tem (Er­werb ei­ner Me...  In­li­ne Fi­nis­hing, Kom­po­nen­ten Ma­te­ria...                    Bay­ern, Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 24.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
109  13.03.2020     B2-55/20  Nor­di­an Ac­qui­si­ti­on 20 B.V., Ams­ter­dam...            Han­del mit Mo­de Ac­ces­soires Schmuck                                                  -                 17.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
110  13.03.2020     B9-48/20  Deut­sche Bör­se AG, Esch­born; Cre­dit Suis­s...  Fonds­ver­triebs­platt­for­men, Fonds­ver­wal­...                                            Hes­sen                 08.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
111  13.03.2020    B9-47/20*  Qa­tar Air­ways Group Q.C.S.C., Do­ha, Ka­tar;...  Gü­ter­be­för­de­rung in der Luft­fahrt, Li­ni...                                                  -  02.04.2020 (*Form­lo­se Ein­stel­lung)
112  13.03.2020     B2-52/20  VfG Ver­triebs­ge­sell­schaft für Ga­stro­no­m...                            Ge­trän­ke­groß­han­del                                   Bay­ern, Hes­sen                 30.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
113  13.03.2020     B1-70/20  Ki­lou­tou SAS, Vil­le­neu­ve-d'Ascq, Frank­re...                                                NaN                                            Hes­sen                 24.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
114  13.03.2020     B3-66/20  Bec­ton, Dickin­son and Com­pa­ny, Fran­klin L...  Me­di­zi­ni­sche Ge­rä­te für die Be­hand­lung...                                                  -                 01.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
115  12.03.2020     B3-59/20  Eu­ro­pean Med­co De­ve­lop­ment 4 S.à r.l. (L...    Ak­ti­ve phar­ma­zeu­ti­sche Wirk­stof­fe (API)                                                  -                 19.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
116  12.03.2020     B3-60/20  FMC Be­tei­li­gungs KG, Bre­men (D); Er­werb d...  sta­tio­näre und am­bu­lan­te Re­ha­bi­li­ta­t...                          Bre­men, Rhein­land-Pfalz                 26.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
117  12.03.2020     B5-46/20  NI­BE In­dus­trier / Wa­ter­kot­te (An­teils- ...  Bat­te­rie-Ener­gie­spei­cher­sys­tem, Erd­ge­...                             Nord­rhein-West­fa­len                 03.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
118  12.03.2020     B4-46/20  SRH Ver­wal­tungs­ge­sell­schaft mbH, Ham­burg...                                 Müll­ver­bren­nung                                           Ham­burg                 06.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
119  12.03.2020     B1-69/20  Ge­sobau AG, Ber­lin; Er­werb ei­ner Mehr­heit...                            Pro­jekt­ge­sell­schaft                                            Ber­lin                 27.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
120  11.03.2020     B1-67/20  Max Weis­haupt GmbH, Schwen­di; Ma­xo­na Ver­w...                                Bü­roim­mo­bi­li­en                      Ba­den-Würt­tem­berg, Bay­ern                 24.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
121  11.03.2020     B4-45/20  Guang­dong Wen­can Die Cas­ting Co., Ldt (Chi­...                     Alu­mi­ni­um­druck­guss­tei­le                                                  -                 06.04.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
122  11.03.2020     B2-54/20  Adi­u­va Ca­pi­tal GmbH, Ham­burg; mit­tel­ba­...           Be­darfs­ge­gen­stän­de, Le­bens­mit­tel                         Ham­burg, Nie­der­sach­sen                 17.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
123  11.03.2020     B1-68/20  Deut­sche Woh­nen As­set Im­mo­bi­li­en GmbH, ...                  Wohn- und Ge­wer­beim­mo­bi­li­en                                  Hes­sen, Sach­sen                 24.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
124  11.03.2020     B7-74/20  On­ta­rio Te­a­chers'Pen­si­on Plan Board, To­...  IT-Si­cher­heits­dienst­leis­tun­gen, IT-Si­ch...                                                  -                 24.03.2020 (Frei­ga­be)
125  10.03.2020     B5-45/20  Kings­pan / Colt In­vest­ments (An­teils- und ...  Hei­zungs-Kli­ma-Lüf­tungs­tech­nik, Park­h­au...                                                NaN                                     NaN
```